# SQL View from 2 tables with FK relationship

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-2008-r2

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have 2 tables like:

```
create table Client
(
    Id int identity(1,1) Primary Key,
    Name varchar(30) not null,
    LastName varchar(30) not null,
    Tel int not null unique,
    Email varchar(30),
    Uwagi varchar(35),
    Problem bit ,
    Wizyty int
);
```

and

```
create table Wizyta
(
    Id int identity(1,1) Primary Key,
    Data date not null,
    IdClient int not null,
    Opis varchar(30),
    DataZapisu date default(getdate()),

    constraint fk_perWizyta 
       foreign key (IdClient) references Client(Id) on delete cascade
);
```

I create a view:

```
create view Tranzakcje as  
(
    Select 
        Data, (Name+ ' ' + LastName) As Client,  
        Opis, DataZapisu  
    from 
        Wizyta w  
    inner join 
        Klient k on k.Id = w.IdKlient
)
```

And it works on my query, but when I execute view from my mobile app I get error :

> SQLException Invalid column name Id.

How to solve it or how to create view with columns `Data Client (Name + LastName) Opis, DataZapisu`.

Comment: You have the Client table spelled with a "K" in the View definition. Does it work when you change that to match the spelling of the actual table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view doesn't actually contain an Id coloumn. If you need it, you have to select whichever Id you want to use.
And also as rhholt commented: you seem to switch between K and C for your Client/Klient table (same goes for field IdClient/IdKlient)...

Comment: Please [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer to improve its readability.